# Pop up redirection javascript

Tags: javascript, popup

I'm learning javascript and am asked to do the below exercise but I'm a bit stuck.

I need to create a pop up which will be displayed automatically after 10 seconds and show a message asking if you want to stay or go to another website; The pop up must be in the middle of the screen.

I can have a pop up after 10 seconds but I'm not sure how to use **if/else** here (currently click on both "ok" and "cancel" will redirect to another page).

```
setTimeout(function() 
    { confirm ("Do you want to leave ? "); 
      location.href = "https://www.youtube.com/"
     }, 10000);
```

Thanks !

Comment: Check the popup documentation. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not going to do your homework. But I can give you a few hits.

Here we go:

1. With the center-aligned popup, you can't use `confirm`. You have to make one with your HTML and CSS.
2. To align popup in center-middle **viewport**. You will need to research these (but not limit) properties: `position`, `z-index`, `top`, `left`, etc.
3. About the redirection, you got the right path. Keep it up.